# Override readonly variable lldb swift

Tags: swift, lldb

Is there a way in lldb to overwrite a readonly variable.

For example if you had a struct

```
struct Object {
    let name: String
}
```

Doing the following in at a breakpoint in Xcode with lldb

```
(lldb) expression object.name = "Tom"
```

Will result in

```
error: <EXPR>:2:19: error: cannot assign to property: 'name' is a get-only property
```

I fully understand why this happens, just want to know if there is an easy way to get around this during debugging?

Please note this is in Swift & **NOT** Objective-C

Comment: Why do you need to overwrite a readonly variable? Since you know you can not change the name of a `Object`, why do not you initialize a new `Object` rather than change the name of it?

Comment: @Joe because when you are debugging and using lldb it is often useful to change one variable at runtime to test different behaviors. If you have a complex object that requires dependency injection simply allocating a new object becomes more complex in your console.

Comment: So why not change the let to var?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `memory write {address}` lldb command to overwrite the memory and change the string value. I managed to do it one address at a time, but it seems like `memory write` is capable of doing it one go.

```
(lldb) help memory write
     Write to the memory of the process being debugged.

Syntax: memory write <cmd-options> <address> <value> [<value> [...]]

Command Options Usage:
  memory write [-f <format>] [-s <byte-size>] <address> <value> [<value> [...]]
  memory write -i <filename> [-s <byte-size>] [-o <offset>] <address> <value> [<value> [...]]

       -f <format> ( --format <format> )
            Specify a format to be used for display.

       -i <filename> ( --infile <filename> )
            Write memory using the contents of a file.

       -o <offset> ( --offset <offset> )
            Start writing bytes from an offset within the input file.

       -s <byte-size> ( --size <byte-size> )
            The size in bytes to use when displaying with the selected format.

     This command takes options and free-form arguments.  If your arguments
     resemble option specifiers (i.e., they start with a - or --), you must use
     ' -- ' between the end of the command options and the beginning of the
     arguments.
```

Here's an example (hopefully someone with more understanding of the lldb and the internals of Swift can provide a better method):

[image: Example using memory write]

This shows overwriting the memory one byte at a time. `po "Tom".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!` gets the hex representation, which is used to step through and overwrite the memory of object.name. I'm sure there's an easier way to do it (in one command), but I couldn't figure out the correct parameter values to pull it off.

Comment: The syntax to replace all the bytes at once is `memory write <address> <size> <byte> <byte> ...`, so for example `memory write 0x1000022c0 -s 1 66 6F 6F 62 61 72`...

Comment: Interesting solution, not ideal but seems to work, thanks.

Comment: @l'L'l Thanks for the answer to that, I was trying something like `memory write 0x1000022c0 -s 6 666F6F626172` which didn't work.  

  
@sbarow Thanks for accepting, it is a pretty cumbersome solution.

Comment: You might also be able to write a string directly using the `-f` switch: `memory write -f s -s <numbytes> -- "Hello, world"` Not sure, though.